# Common UIAcitivityIndicator for all view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I have multiple view controllers in my application.

While downloading data from server, I can start a `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

But the problem is for three different view controllers I need to create three different `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

I want to initialize `UIActivityIndicatorView` only once in some place so I can display or hide it. No need to create or initialize `UIActivityIndicatorView` as many as view controllers.

How can I do this? Any help.

Comment: [self.window addSubview:loadingView];

Answer (score 1):

Add your loading indicator on window in your appdelgate like this

First initialize your loading view

```
-(void)InitializeLoadingIndictor
 {
   loadingView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 400, 150, 150)];
   [loadingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   [loadingView setAlpha:0.6];
    [loadingView setHidden:YES];
   [loadingView.layer setCornerRadius:10];
    [_window addSubview:loadingView];
   loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
   [loadingIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];

  [loadingView addSubview:loadingIndicator];
}
```

Then create two methods two hide and show it

```
+ (void)showLoading
 {
  [loadingView setHidden:NO];
  [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
 }
```

Hide it

```
+ (void)hideLoading
 {
  [loadingView setHidden:YES];
 }
```

Then in your view controller, call it as

```
    [AppDelegate showLoading];
```

And to hide it when your are done

```
    [AppDelegate hideLoading];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom UIAlertView to show your indicator.
I have made two custom files using which you can show indicator without initializing it again and again.

files are:
//header file..

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProgressIndicator : UIAlertView
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}

@end
```

//implementation file

```
#import "ProgressIndicator.h"

@implementation ProgressIndicator

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        activityIndicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    // Drawing code
}

@end
```

//using this files in your controller..

```
#import "ProgressIndicator.h"

ProgressIndicator *progressIndicator=[[ProgressIndicator alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[progressIndicator show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD link. You will get custom Activity indicator for all the views.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the answers. Below code works for me.

AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)StartLoading
{
    loader = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    loader.frame = CGRectMake(50, 14, 20, 20);
    [loader startAnimating];
    [self.window addSubview:loader];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:loader];
}

-(void)EndLoading
{
    for(UIView *subview in [self.window subviews])
    {
       if(subview==loader)
         [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```